# How to automate PEM pass phrase when generating OpenSSL cert?

Tags: ssl, openssl, passwords, tls1.2, passphrase

I am needing to automate the generation of self signed SSL certificates for testing purposes for a project. I am generating a certificate and key using the following OpenSSL command:

```
> openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout myserver.key -out myserver.crt -subj "/C=US/ST=California/L=San Diego/O=Development/OU=Dev/CN=example.com"
```

During generation you are prompted to create a PEM pass phrase:

```
Enter PEM pass phrase:
Verifying - Enter PEM pass phrase:
```

How can I automate this? I have tried the `-passin` argument like this:

```
openssl ...... -passin pass:foobar .....
```

also

```
openssl ...... -passin file:secretfile.txt .....
```

But in both cases it still asks for to create a `PEM pass phrase`. From what I read I think that `passin` is only adding a password to the key file...

Is it possible to automate this somehow?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The process creates a password protected key file. It thus needs a password which gets used to store this **output** file. But the `-passin` argument you use is for reading an **input** file. From the [documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/1/req):

> -passin arg  - the **input** file password source

Instead you need the proper option to specify the output password, i.e.

> -passout arg -  the **output** file password source

Comment: Ah I totally misunderstood that. Thank you!